# como sacar un promedio en una consulta sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, wamp

Podrían ayudarme a resolver esta duda que tengo.
Necesito que se muestre para cada tipo sanguíneo que cantidad de empleados la posee, mostrando también el porcentaje total de empleados de la empresa representa dicha cantidad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí el problema es que en porcentaje me muestra el numero de Id_Tipo en lugar de mostrar un porcentaje, en esta base de datos solo tengo 3 empleados, el porcentaje que espero seria un 33.33 % de cada uno.

Comment: seguro que `avg` sirve para sacar porcentajes?

Comment: Por lo que yo investigue si, pero no estoy seguro

Comment: promedio no es lo mismo que porcentaje

Comment: ocupas una regla de 3

Comment: Podrías orientarme en como se tendría que hacer, porque la verdad ya estoy bloqueado

Comment: mas o menos que fuera: **count(z.tipo_sangre) * 100 / total_empleados** es decir el conteo que obtenga por cada tipo de sangre * 100 entre el total de empleados registrados, imagina si de 5000 empleados 40 tuvieron sangre **O+** entonces la operación sería 40* 100 / 5000

Comment: shadow Muchas gracias por el apoyo

Comment: no hay de que, de hecho la respuesta de @A.Cedano te lo soluciona te sugiero la aceptes calificandola y la apliques

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Para  sacar el porcentaje puedes:

- sacar el total de empleados que hay (en una subconsulta por ejemplo: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM empleado`)
- multiplicar ese total por 100
- dividir el total de filas entre el total de empleados por 100

La consulta quedaría así:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS Total,
    t.descripcion,
    ( COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM empleado)*100 ) `%`
FROM empleado e
    INNER JOIN tipo_sanguineo t ON e.tipo_sangre=t.id_tipo
GROUP BY e.tipo_sangre;
```

**Salida:**

```
Total   descripcion    %
-------------------------------
1       A+             33,3333
1       A-             33,3333
1       B+             33,3333
```

---

### Código de prueba en línea

**<kbd>[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](https://rextester.com/YOVP71615)</kbd>**

Comment: Muchisimas gracias amigo. Estaba ya super revuelto y no sabia como llegar al resultado de esa consulta.